# double check: using an internal camera microphone WITH an XLR input 

Tags: location-recording

I would like to know if it would be possible to get the output from the internal microphone on the camera (I'll find out the exact model name for you, it's for a pilot I'm working on next weekend) as well as recording the output from an me66 mic on a boom pole. At the same time

The trick in recording it will be to pan the int camera mic to the left (lets say) and the me66 mic (on the xlr input) to the right. We have basically no budget so we can get the basics, it would be nice to get a set recorder but If I can get a boompole, me 66 and a fluffy that's fine.

I'm working on the idea that we will only have 1 camera and that's where my idea of panning the two different mics on the camera comes in.

I want to do this so that I have more choice when it comes to editing the sound in post.

Can it be done because I've been trained to always switch off the int mic on the camera when using an XLR input. Besides the phasing which could be fixable in post (there may be a a few split seconds delay) can it be done?
The challenge is that it's all on tape in the camera so playback might not be possible after a take.

Thanks sonic samurais

Answer (score 1):

Most cameras switch the internal off as soon as you plug in and external source. You will need to grab the manual for your camera to find out. Most manufacturers have their manuals online if you don't have access to the original one that came with the camera.

The other option if you are in areas that has easy access to power is to grab a mixing desk (i don't assume that you can get a field mixer) and 2 mics (beg, borrow but don't steal) and run the panned mix directly into the camera.

One thing to note which ever way you go is to try to off the auto gain system if the camera it and manually set your levels. All these things will come down to the camera you are using, so study that manual and get the equipment before going on set and do tests (if you can).

Good luck!

Comment: it's the sony z1, i dont have the manual and will only inspect on the shoot. It runs on tape and not sd card which frightens me because how will i know if the int mic and the ext me66 are panned correctly! can the camera pan the recording inputs? We only have one shot at getting this pilot right abd I dont want false security only to realize im in a shit storm when it comes to post

Comment: the on board mic is stereo which sort of messes with my plan because i want to have the xlr on the left and the onboard on the right. If the inboard is stereo then im screwed. Is there anyway to make the onboard mic mono? I'm panicy because i cant play back what's been recorded!

Comment: Seriously, grab the manual from the sony website for the camera.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the camera. On a Panasonic HVX200 it can be done pretty easily. But different cameras have different features.